# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

При попытке произвести join элементов списка из yaml файла и передать индекс переменной перед значением id

получаю ошибку

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got
> 'string'

arg.yml

```
id_list:
  - '123a'
  - '221c'
  - '332a'
```

script.py

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import yaml
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("."))
templ2 = env.get_template("template.txt")

with open('arg.yml') as f:
    arg = yaml.safe_load(f)

with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(templ2.render(arg))
```

template.txt

```
Some text {{ ', ' .join(f'id{i} = {x}' for i, x in enumerate (id_list, 1))}}
```

Ожидаемый результат

`Some text id1=123a,id2=221c,id3=332a`